# Rails 6 update attributes only if params exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got `event` model which `belongs_to :user` and have fields: `name, start_at, end_at, duration, status`. In my controller I want to allow user to update 3 of them: `start_date, end_date, duration` like below:

```
class EventsController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:update]
  before_action :set_event, only: [:update]
  attr_reader :event, :user
  
  def update
    ::Events::Update.new(event, params.permit(:start_date, :end_date, :duration, :user_id, :id)).call
  end

  private

  def set_event
    @event = user.events.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

To update `Event` record I'm using below service:

```
module Events
  class Update
    attr_reader :params, :event

    def initialize(event, params)
      @event = event
      @params = params
    end

    def call
      event.update!(
        start_date: params[:start_date],
        end_date: params[:end_date],
        duration: params[:duration]
      )
    end
  end
end
```

How to handle situation when e.g. `start_date` and `end_date` are not provided (user won't change it) and user to passed only `duration` to change this value? in current implementation I'm getting an error:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "start_date" of relation "events" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: Why are you permitting all those attributes (`params.permit(:start_date, :end_date, :duration, :user_id, :id)`)? You can simply permit less `params.permit(:start_date, :end_date, :duration)` and then use `event.update!(params)`

Comment: @AbM because I'm getting something like: ```Event Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."user_id" = $1 AND "events"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/api/v1/events_controller.rb:38:in `set_event'
Unpermitted parameters: :user_id, :id```

Comment: That is just a warning. If you aren't using those attributes, you can disregard the warning.

Comment: @AbM ok but I'm gonna need the `id` of event to find it in db so yeah,         `params.permit(:start_date, :end_date, :duration, :id)` will be the end result. Is it ok to pass it in permit? I don't like this approach tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Events::Update` class is overkill. Just do it like this:

```
class EventsController
  def update
    @event = Event.where(user_id: params[:user_id]).find(params[:id])
    @event.update!(event_params)
    # redirect_to ??? # typically you don't render a template here, but redirect to a show or index action.
  end

  private
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:start_date, :end_date, :duration)
    end
end
```

- You only have one action, so there's no point splitting out your AREL lookups into separate methods
- You don't need to make two separate AREL lookups to get your user's event
- Creating a service class just to run a single update is silly
- You should be passing your params within the scope of an `event` ... this is default if you have a `form_for @event` standard Rails form
- You don't need the `attr_reader` line since you're setting them as instance variables
- You don't need the separate @user variable, you can get it from @event.user in your view (although that will generate an additional query anyway)
- although ... why are you rendering from your `update` action? Surely you should be redirecting somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! it's an app with API only mode (`ActionController::API`) so I need to render serialized json, I don't have views. If I use `params.require(:event)....` I'll got `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: event):`

Comment: It'll be because the shape of the data you're submitting is wrong. In your request you just need to nest your event attributes within an `{ event: { attributes: "here" } }` object.